# Как из 'b' сделать "b" (из char в string)

Tags: c++, строки, vector

Мне необходимо в вектор строк `vector<string>` добавить два символа `char first = 'a'` и `char second = 'b'`, но в моем коде не определенные символы, то есть мне нужен метод или что-то похожее. Прошу не приводить огромные решения, я новичок))
Пытался сделать через `to_string(static_cast<char> (first))`, но не получилось

Comment: `vect.push_back(string(&first, 1))`

Comment: Что значит "в вектор строк vector<string> добавить два символа"? В vector<string> можно добавить только другие строки. Или нужно добавить в вектор строки с такими символами? Или наоборот, в те строки, которые уже есть в векторе добавить символы?

Comment: В элемент вектора ( в строку, так как элемент это строка ) добавить такие символы

Comment: ну тогда `vec[index].push_back(first); vec[index].push_back(second);`

Comment: @αλεχολυτ кажется тема дубликата несколько не такая

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string s(1,'a');
```

создает строку `s` с содержимым `"a"`.

Добавить в вектор можно соответственно как

```
v.emplace_back(1,'a');
```

Вот примеры - https://ideone.com/0XUafF